# How to optimize my Trie implementation so that I don't get OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, trie, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm implementing text predictions using a very simple Trie implementation, which is a slightly modified version of this [code](http://blog.csdn.net/williamcs/article/details/8268544)

It performs better than I initially expected, but I'm receiving an `OutOfMemoryError` frequently. Any ideas how can solve this problem by either:

- increasing the memory designated to my app
- optimizing the implementation to use less memory

or any other suggestions?

I've seen recommendations that the memory limitation problems could be avoided by using a native implementation of a part of the code, but I would prefer to stay in Java, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try turning on largeHeap in your manifest to see if it helps:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Comment: I think it is still relevant as answer, because it refers to the option a: how to increase the memory allocated to my app.

Comment: Great, glad to know it worked.  Of course optimizing the implementation in addition would be beneficial and largeHeap has some limitations as pointed out on the android developer page.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `this.next = new Node[R];` the implementation allocates an array with 26 pointers to nodes on level 1, then 26^26 pointers to nodes on level 2, then 26^26^26 on level 3 and so on. That could be one reason you run out of memory.

You can try and change the implementation so that every Node has a HashMap of nodes with a small initial capacity, say 5. The HashMap will grow only when there's a real need - which will save some memory.

Another problem in that code is with the `delete`:

```
    // delete a node  
    public void delete(Node node) {  
        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {  
            if(node.next != null) {  
                delete(node.next[i]);  
            }  
        }  
        node = null;  // <-- this is not doing anything!
    }
```

The reason it's not doing anything is that the reference to the node is passed `by value` in Java - so the *real* reference remains intact. What you should do instead is:

```
    // delete a node  
    public void delete(Node node) {  
        for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {  
            if(node.next != null) {  
                delete(node.next[i]);  
                node.next[i] = null; // <-- here you nullify the actual array item
            }                        // which makes the object a good candidate for 
                                     // the next time GC will run
        }              
    }
```

So it could also be a memory leak - in case you counted on `delete` to free space.

Comment: No, the delete isn't used at all. I'm implementing a text suggestion mechanism, so I very often need most of the 26 pointers. I imagined that using a `HashMap` instead would be much worse performance wise, but I may try it out to see!

Comment: @AmirAfghani had you taken a better look at the code I posted via the link, you would have noticed that the delete is not invoked, so again, the code posted is a very good description of the problem. Btw, what's that "gee" you're saying, what does it mean?